# Ouput Count as Values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am quite new to SQL and would like to achieve the following...

Input:

```
-------------------------
Name  | Surname  | Age
-------------------------
Name1 | Surname1 | Age1a
Name1 | Surname1 | Age1b
Name2 | Surname2 | Age2a
Name2 | Surname2 | Age2b
```

Output:

```
-------------------------------
Name  | Surname  | PossibleAges
-------------------------------
Name1 | Surname1 | Age1a, Age1b
Name2 | Surname2 | Age2a, Age2b
```

I guess there should definitely by a GROUP BY Name and Surname, but I have no idea how to create the PossibleAges column.

Comment: Offtopic, but storing ages into database is usually not the best idea - they tend to change over time; of course you could store ages at certain events (marriage, death) to make queries or analysis simpler/faster.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name, thanks, I have added the DBMS.

Comment: @Arvo, this was just an example! My real input contains work-related information that I should not necessarily share online ;) Thank you for your answer though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [string_agg()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) :

```
select name, surname, 
       string_agg(PossibleAges, ', ') within group (order by PossibleAges) as PossibleAges
from table t
group by name, surname;
```

For older version you can use xml approach :

```
select name, surname,
       stuff(( select concat(', ', t1.PossibleAges)
               from table t1
               where t1.name = t.name and t1.surname = t.surname
               for xml path('')
             ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as PossibleAges
from (select distinct name, surname from table t) t;
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your answer! Unfortunately I get the following error message:
'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Do you know of any workaround?

Comment: @ijswift. . . You can use older style with `xml` approach.

Comment: I am receiving an error message for line 4 saying that the multi-part identifier could not be bound...